# Plesk API - dynamically create .htaccess on new domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, plesk

I'm using the Plesk API (1.6.0.2) to add new domain names. However, I'd like to generate specific .htaccess rules for newly created domains.

I tried using PHP's file_put_contents on the newly created path, but I got an open_basedir error. Changing the open_basedir paths manually sort of defeats the purpose of the script, which is to automate the creation the virtual hosts and their domains.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can do a lot with just a skeleton dir & using `%{SERVER_NAME}` instead of a custom domainname in .htaccess rules. Is there anything unique besides that that you need custom .htaccesses?

Comment: Yes, the hope is to proxy the newly created domain to a URL that contains a user variable. This variable is derived during domain-creation and so I'm looking for a way to get it into the .htaccess file.

Comment: When you create a new domain, don't you also have create an (S)FTP account or something to use for that domain? Could use that...

Comment: Good point -- I was able to use PHP's ftp_login with the FTP account that was created to connect and insert a dynamically generated htaccess file. @Wrikken, if you post as an answer I'll mark it as solved.